# Adding a Humorous "Skills" line to Resume: Yes or No?

Tags: professionalism, resume

[image]

So if you don't 'see' it, then please look at the last 'skill' in the image. I think it's a nice way to end the resume as my 'education' portion resulted in no degree but is there to show that I am educated - just not formally.

So, yes or no?

Comment: How will the OCR software used by many HR departments interpret your resume?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you're not sure about including something in your resume, don't.

Comment: Good to see you didn't give yourself full marks for grammar....

Comment: Humor aside, I'm not sure "progress bars" as you have done are a good way to highlight skills.

Comment: A former colleague of mine has "generous lover" listed as a skill on LinkedIn.  He has received more endorsements for it from colleagues than any of his other skills.  But I'd leave that sort of thing off a paper resumé.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but your entire resume looks like a joke to me.

Comment: WRT the progress bar (and the whole skills section) - many people don't read this bit - they look in your job history for where you've applied the skills.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom Makes sense that he'd be so heavily endorsed if he really >is< that generous!

Comment: If I saw this "joke" on a resume I was reviewing, I would have myself a good little chuckle.  Then I would toss it the bin.  Firstly, I'm almost certainly not hiring someone to write resumes.  Secondly, if there's even *the slightest hint* of bullshit on a resume, it makes me wonder *what else is fake?*  Maybe nothing is an outright lie, but he's clearly comfortable including material that isn't entirely straightforward.

Comment: I do not think that people will pick up the joke. Usually, people are scanning, not reading resume. In few seconds, the decision will be computed: keep or discard. I do not think people will make link between two elements in that lapse of time.

Comment: @Steve-O On the other hand, it could be read as being brutally honest about one's own capabilities.

Comment: Your Windows Update is nearly done.

Answer (score 16):

Bad idea.

Unless you're applying for a job as a comedian (in which case think of a better joke).

For any serious job, you stick with conventional style and let your accomplishments do the rest. For a very low level job it might be ok.

Answer (score 10):

Humor is contextual.  You can't build a context in a resume, nor do you know your audience.  It may work once or twice, but that will be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Would the context not be the resume itself? And if the resume sucks, then the joke would be right there at the end, no? :)

Comment: The resume is not the context. The context is the collective experience of the audience, which you have no knowledge.

Comment: There are universal things in life that don't require specific knowledge of an audience to know they understand something. 

I believe every man or woman who ever applied or hired for a job would get it.

Comment: @Newbie - if your resume sucks, no joke is going to make anyone think "ah, well, at least he made a joke about it - let's bring him in"

Comment: @Newbie - You asked a question.  Here is your answer.  If you don't want to listen to the answer, that's your prerogative.  However, you're not going to keep "arguing" this to somehow find validation for a really bad idea.  Take the answer or don't, but this is the answer you asked for.

Comment: Humor is very personal: what one person considers funny, the other finds boring, offensive, whatever... You cannot antipicate how it will be received without the context of knowing the recipient.

Answer (score 6):

Your resume is a formal document, just the fact of trying to use humor in it will be seen as unprofessional by some.

You don't know who will see your resume, and you'd better try to avoid being rejected immediately for such a small addition.
If your resume is "terrible" as you wrote in a comment, humor is not the way you should solve the problem.

Be sure to keep your resume short and focused on yourself and your work experience. You can find a lot of tips on writing a successful resume on many sites.

Last of all, it's normal not to receive a reply if they're not interested in your position, and that's why you should be applying to a lot of places at once, expecially if you're in an oversaturated job market or if you have no previous experience.

Answer (score 4):

I would have to say **NO** do not do it. You may find it funny but how can you guarantee your viewer will? If they don't find it funny, they'll bin it without a second thought. They may not even realise it's a joke and if you get through to the interview stages they may ask *why* you put it on which could lead to awkwardness when you tell them it was meant to be humorous and they don't laugh.

Additionally I don't think the use of progress bars is useful. Don't measure your skills like that. Anything you put on your CV, make sure you're good at it. Sell yourself. Right now you're giving off the vibe that you're not as good at multitasking as I would like you to be.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your employer humorously says

"Our job offer is ranging from $0.5555555 - $50.5555555 per day depending on your experience"

If you want to be looked as a professional. You have to act professionally.
First impression is very important.

Comment: If the employer responded to the resume, then it was better than 70% of all the others. 

And I'd be happy to take an income halfway between .55 and $50, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Its not our decision its yours. Goodluck :)